# Moving carbon nanotube in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

When a metal wire moves across a magnetic field, voltage is induced across it, which is equal to $BLV$, where $B$ is strength of magnetic field, $L$ is the length of wire and $V$ is its velocity. Will a carbon nanotube also exhibit this phenomenon? I am asking this because carbon nanotube is although a good conductor of electricity, but probably that is because of some quantum phenomenon (bulk carbon is bad conductor of electricity).

Comment: Good question, i think it is better suited at physics stack exchange...

Answer (score 1):

A carbon nanotube is a conductor.

It is somehow a 'rolled graphene sheet' and the material graphite (stack of graphene layers) is quite a famous conductor.

What characterize the carbon nanotube is its 'fairly' good strength, together with a ballistic conduction.

Therefore as for any conductor, the equation `emf = B.L.V` is perfectly valid (the equation reflect an accumulation of charges on both ends of the wire)

Obviously if your wire is too short (let say <0.5um long) then you may have to start considering a bit more your system but with other conductors it would be the same.